# How to properly concatenate values coming from Javascript and PHP?

Tags: javascript, php

I have been struggling with this for the last two hours and I can't get it to work. Take a look to the following piece of code:

```
$js = '$.extend($.fn.fmatter , {
            userActions : function(cellvalue, options, rowData, addOrEdit) {
            var data = cellvalue.split("|");
            var id = options.rowId;
            var actions = "";';

foreach ($editorActions as $linkType => $value) {
    switch ($linkType) {
        case 'view':
            $js .= "if(data[1] == 1) {
                        actions += \"<a class='actionimage' href='" . $value . " + options.rowId' title='" . $this->translate->_e('View') . "' onClick='load_start();'><img src='/images/icons/16x16/document_view.png' width='16' height='16' alt='' /></a>\";
                    }";
    }

    break;
}
```

As you can see `id` is a value coming from Javascript and `$value` is coming from PHP. The idea is to get an hyperlink as for example:

```
$value = "/route/to/function/";
id = 19009; // I've omitted the $ sign since this var is coming from JS

var href = "' . $value . '" + id;'
```

Then I need to use the `href` var as part of the `<a>` element shown right after the definition.

With my code above I am getting this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Can I get some help to get this right?

**UPDATE:**

This is how the code looks like after I render the page:

```
$(function () {
    $.extend($.fn.fmatter, {
        userActions: function (cellvalue, options, rowdata) {
            var data = cellvalue.split('|');
            var id = options.rowId;
            var actions = '';

            console.log(id);
            if (data[1] == 1) {
                actions += "<a class='actionimage' href='/sf/distributor/show/ + options.rowId' title='View' onClick='load_start();'><img src='/images/icons/16x16/document_view.png' width='16' height='16' alt='' /></a>";
            }

            return actions;
        }
    });
});
```

Notice how the function `$.extend` close properly. `console.log(id)` did print the value of `options.rowId` however this value doesn't have any effect on the hyperlink as you may notice this is the value `/sf/distributor/show/ + options.rowId`.

What is coming in `$value` is a plain string in the case above `/sf/distributor/show/`.

Comment: @Carcigenicate this will be rendered as a Javascript code on the view aftewards so there `id` will have sense

Comment: never mix php with js - it's bad practice and should be avoided at all costs. E.g. you can add data tags to dom elements to get your php data and assign it to a js var to use..

Comment: On which line you are getting Uncaught SyntaxError

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs I wish not need to do that but I come latest to this company and them already had this develop now is giving a lot of issues and there is not time to refactoring this in the proper way as you said :-(

Comment: @ReynierPM aww I hear you, similar situation xD good luck :'(

Comment: @Carcigenicate nop I am not trying to parse such `id` on PHP because it won't exists there, you're right, I need to append that `id` to the string coming from PHP so when this get's rendered on the view then `id` takes the proper value and I end up with a full URL

Comment: You may want to take a look at your rendered javascript to see where the issue might be. Make sure that it's getting written to the page correctly.

Comment: `$js = '$.extend($.fn.fmatter , {` you are closing these brackets after your foreach and just haven't shown us that...?

Comment: @Popnoodles the code is large that's why I have omitted that too but don't worry that is not the issue since that gets close properly

Comment: How do you know that this piece is causing the issue?

Comment: @ReynierPM What is in `$value`? It should be properly escaped if you are including it in a JavaScript string. You would get that error for instance, if `$value` contained a newline character or a double quote character, because you haven't escaped it.

Comment: maybe sharing the outputted JS will help

Comment: ok guys take a look to the update, hopefully that should help to understand better the issue

Comment: @ReynierPM Your outputted code doesn't even have the `var href = "` line?

Comment: @Paulpro no more href ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing double quotes and to end and reopen the string around `options.rowId` and a `+` in:

```
actions += \"<a class='actionimage' href='" . $value . " + options.rowId'
```

It should be:

```
actions += \"<a class='actionimage' href='" . $value . "\" + options.rowId + \"'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you are missing "" and that way you are adding options.rowId as a string text.

```
href='/sf/distributor/show/" + options.rowId + "'
```